# JPA Hibernate ManyToMany JOIN query o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « where »

Tags: hibernate, jpa

here's an update of my problem

Here's the entities I'm been using:

```
    enter code here

      
  
        package org.vaadin.example;
        
        import java.util.HashSet;
        import java.util.Set;
        
        import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
        import javax.persistence.Entity;
        import javax.persistence.FetchType;
        import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
        import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
        import javax.persistence.Id;
        import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
        import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
        import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
        import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
        import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
        import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
        
        @Entity 
        public class Shoe {
            @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
            private int idShoe;
            
            private String marque;
            
            @OneToOne
            private Person demandeur;
            
            @OneToOne
            private Shop vendeur;
            
            private String link;
            
            private String category;
            
            private String size;
            
            private String sizeUE;
            
            private String sizeUS;
            
            private String sizeCM;
        
            private String reservation;
            
            private String prix;
        
             
             @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
             @JoinTable( name = "Shoes_Asked_By_Shops_Associations",
                                    joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "idShop" ),
                                    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "idShoe" ),
                                    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
                                             "idShop", "idShoe" }))
            
            
        
             public Set<Shop> shoesByShopAsked = new HashSet<Shop>();
            
             public int getIdShoe() {
                return idShoe;
             }
        
            public void setIdShoe(int id) {
                this.idShoe = id;
            }
        
            public String getReservation() {
                return reservation;
            }
        
            public void setReservation(String reservation) {
                this.reservation = reservation;
            }
        
            public String getCategory() {
                return category;
            }
        
            public void setCategory(String category) {
                this.category = category;
            }
        
            public String getSize() {
                return size;
            }
        
            public void setSize(String size) {
                this.size = size;
            }
        
            public Person getDemandeur() {
                return demandeur;
            }
        
            public void setDemandeur(Person demandeur) {
                this.demandeur = demandeur;
            }
        
            public String getMarque() {
                return marque;
            }
        
            public void setMarque(String marque) {
                this.marque = marque;
            }
        
            public Shop getVendeur() {
                return vendeur;
            }
        
            public void setVendeur(Shop vendeur) {
                this.vendeur = vendeur;
            }
        
            public String getLink() {
                return link;
            }
        
            public void setLink(String link) {
                this.link = link;
            }
        
            public String getPrix() {
                return prix;
            }
        
            public void setPrix(String prix) {
                this.prix = prix;
            }
        
            public String getSizeUE() {
                return sizeUE;
            }
        
            public void setSizeUE(String sizeUE) {
                this.sizeUE = sizeUE;
            }
        
            public String getSizeUS() {
                return sizeUS;
            }
        
            public void setSizeUS(String sizeUS) {
                this.sizeUS = sizeUS;
            }
        
            public String getSizeCM() {
                return sizeCM;
            }
        
            public void setSizeCM(String sizeCM) {
                this.sizeCM = sizeCM;
            }
        
            public Set<Shop> getShoesByShopAsked() {
                return shoesByShopAsked;
            }
        
            public void setShoesByShopAsked(Set<Shop> shoesByShopAsked) {
                this.shoesByShopAsked = shoesByShopAsked;
            }
            
            
        }
        
   
        
        And the shop entities :
        
   
        package org.vaadin.example;
    
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.Set;
    
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
    
    @Entity
    public class Shop {
    
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int idShop;
        
        @OneToOne
        private Address adresse;
        
        private String telephone;
        
        private String name;
        
        private String email;
    
        @OneToOne
        private Person gerant;
        
        private String photo;
        
        private boolean active;
        
         @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
         @JoinTable( name = "Brands_Shops_Associations",
                                joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "idShop" ),
                                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "idBrand" ),
                                uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
                                         "idShop", "idBrand" }))
         
         
        public Set<Brand> brandsByShop = new HashSet<Brand>();
        
         
         @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
         @JoinTable( name = "Shoes_Asked_By_Shops_Associations",
                                joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "idShop" ),
                                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "idShoe" ),
                                uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
                                         "idShop", "idShoe" }))
         
         
    
        public Set<Shoe> shoesByShopAsked = new HashSet<Shoe>();
         
        public Shop () {
            
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hashCode(idShop);
        }
          
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Shop other = (Shop) obj;
            return Objects.equals(idShop, other.getIdShop());
        }
    
        public int getIdShop() {
            return idShop;
        }
    
        public String getNom() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setNom(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public void setIdShop(int id) {
            this.idShop = id;
        }
    
        public Address getAdresse() {
            return adresse;
        }
    
        public void setAdresse(Address adress) {
            this.adresse = adress;
        }
    
        public String getPhoto() {
            return photo;
        }
    
        public void setPhoto(String photo) {
            this.photo = photo;
        }
    
        public String getTelephone() {
            return telephone;
        }
    
        public void setTelephone(String phoneNumber) {
            this.telephone = phoneNumber;
        }
    
    
        public void setGerant(Person gerant) {
            this.gerant = gerant;
        }
    
        public Person getGerant() {
            return this.gerant;
        }
    
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
    
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
    
        public boolean isActive() {
            return active;
        }
    
        public void setActive(boolean active) {
            this.active = active;
        }
    
        public Set<Brand> getBrandsByShop() {
            return brandsByShop;
        }
    
        public void setBrandsByShop(Set<Brand> brandsByShop) {
            this.brandsByShop = brandsByShop;
        }
    
        public void addBrand(Brand brand) {
            this.brandsByShop.add(brand);
            brand.getShopByBrand().add(this);
        }
        public Set<Shoe> getShoesByShopAsked() {
            return shoesByShopAsked;
        }
        public void setShoesByShopAsked(Set<Shoe> shoesByShopAsked) {
            this.shoesByShopAsked = shoesByShopAsked;
            
        }
        
        public void addShoe(Shoe shoe) {
            this.shoesByShopAsked.add(shoe);
            shoe.getShoesByShopAsked().add(this);
        }``
    
    }
    
And my JPA query :

        
        
        
            @Query("select s from Shoe s join Shop u where u.idShop = :idShop")
            public Set<Shoe> findAllByShop(int idShop);
       

EDIT within the following repository I get empty set :

package org.vaadin.example.repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.vaadin.example.Person;
import org.vaadin.example.Shoe;
import org.vaadin.example.Shop;

public interface ShoeRepository  extends JpaRepository<Shoe, Long>  {
    
    public Shoe findByIdShoe(int idShoe);
    
    public List<Shoe> findAllByDemandeur(Person demandeur); 

    @Query("select s from Shoe s where s.vendeur.idShop = :idShop")
    public Set<Shoe> findAllByShop(int idShop);
    
}


and my call in my vaadin view :

        private void buildGrid () {
            
            Set<Shoe> shoesList = new HashSet<Shoe>();
            String email = VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute("email").toString();
            Shop shop = this.shopService.findByEmail(email);
            shoesList = this.shoeService.findAllByShop(shop.getIdShop());
            labelSize = new Label("Nombre de chaussures en demandées " + shoesList.size());
            add(labelSize);
            grid.setMinWidth("1200px");     
            
            grid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_NO_BORDER,
                    GridVariant.LUMO_NO_ROW_BORDERS, GridVariant.LUMO_ROW_STRIPES);
            grid.setItems(shoesList);
            grid.addComponentColumn(item -> createRemoveButton(grid, item)).setHeader("Actions");
            grid.addComponentColumn(item -> createDeleteButton(grid, item)).setHeader("Actions");
            grid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.NONE);
            grid.setClassName("v-margin-right");
            grid.setHeight("900px");
            grid.setMinHeight("650px");
            add(grid);
        }
```

when I call the method :
shoesList = this.shoeService.findAllByShop(shop.getIdShop());

it return an empty list but inside my db it's not empty Shoe, Shop and the association shoes_asked_by_shops_associations are not empty.

I'm really confused ..

Comment: Why do you join Shop and Shop?

Comment: Hi Simon, I think I'm been joining Shop and Shoe ?

Answer (score 1):

Solve by using the method shop.getShoesByShopAsked instead of calling a service !

Thx for your time

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to to explicitly join because you mapped the relationship.

```
@Query("select s from Shoe s where s.vendeur.idShop = :idShop")
public Set<Shoe> findAllByShop(int idShop);
```